# How can use variables for the row and columns in setCellFormula in the xlsx package in R?

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I am trying to create a formula in a cell of an existing Excel document. I can easily do it this way:

```
#Load workbook
  wb<-loadWorkbook('test.xlsx') #Let this be any xlsx document with borders on cell B1 of Sheet2
#Get tab 
  tab=wb$getSheet('Sheet2')  
  rows<-getRows(tab)
  cells <- getCells(rows)
#You can set a formula in a cell
  cells$'1.2'$setCellFormula("A1") #Cell B1 will now have the formula "=A1"
  cells$`1.2`
#Save the workbook with a new name
  saveWorkbook(wb,"test2.xlsx")
```

What I would like to do is to be able to easily modify the address of the cell based on variables that I would calculate beforehand. Some thing such as:

```
#You can set a formula in a cell
  r<-1
  c<-2
  cells$'r.c'$setCellFormula("A1") #Cell B1 will now have the formula "=A1"
  cells$`r.c`
```

I tried something like this:

```
eval(paste0("cells$`",r,".",c,"'$setCellFormula('A1')"))
```

but all I get is:

> [1] "cells$`2.2'$setCellFormula('A1')"

Does any one know how I can easily replace the row and column numbers by variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `parse` the text before `eval`uating it:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("cells$'",r,".",c,"'$setCellFormula('A1')")))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, when I try to create a formula pointing to a different tab like this:
eval(parse(text=paste0("cells$'",r,".",c,"'$setCellFormula('Sheet 3'!A1)")))
I get the following error message:
Error in parse(text = paste0("cells$'", r, ".", c, "'$setCellFormula('Sheet 3'!A1)")) : 
  <text>:1:37: unexpected '!'
1: cells$'1.2'$setCellFormula('Sheet 3'!
I tried escaping the "!" but it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: I would try to use `setCellFormula(cell,formula)` function directly instead of parsing text but I didn't find a description of this function in `xlsx` package documentation